# Can I replace a 26"/2,0 rim with a 26"/1.75 rim?

Tags: rims, aluminum, 26-inch

My bike's front rim bent and I want to replace it.

I bought a **Apollo Summit 10** for 250$

After some time the front rim bent when I fell down on the street and when I asked in the market its 120$ for a **26"/2.0** aluminium front wheel.

I searched for the rim online and i found one that is **26"/1.75** Can I use **26"/1.75** aluminium rim for the same Tyre and Tube?

Is it going to work properly ?

Comment: A bent rim isn't a dead end in many cases (it depends on how its been bent). A bit of labor at the bike shop can usually bring them to working condition in many cases for much less than a new wheel.

Comment: yes but that rim got bend very badly so  i really need to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.0 is the diameter of the tyre/tube in inches.  So a 1.75" tyre will be smaller and slimmer, and probably a little faster.

26" is the diameter of the whole rim, but check the tyre for its ISO number to be sure.  Its likely to be a ISO-559 size.

**answer**: yes that rim will probably fit fine.  You'll need to check and adjust rim brakes, or if its disc brakes then that needs to be right too.

Front wheels tend to survive better than back wheels.  If you're after a replacement wheel search out a local bike cooperative.  Our has dozens of spare front wheels and a lack of good rears.

Answer (score 1):

My experience when a rim is advertised with an inches width [Rather than an internal diameter in MM] it's much more of a general statement. Chances are that you will be able to use the exact same tire you used before.

Generally a 1.75" tire fits just fine on rims with internal widths of 17mm to 26mm with out any real hazard. If you go outside of that range there is a higher chance of burping the tire, having a blowout, or popping a bead on hard turning. A 2.00" tire will safely fit on a 19mm to 28mm internal width. So if the inner width of your new rim falls between 19 and 26mm you can use the exact same tire you had previously. If the internal width is 17 or 18mm then i would consider a slightly narrower tire such as the 1.75" or a 1.95"

With that said i would check to see if they list an internal rim width on the site your looking at, this will be an indicator as to what sizes of tire it will work best with.

Having a more narrow tire on the front however is neither uncommon nor problematic.